# How can I find the convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n{1 \over 2n+1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n{1 \over 2n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $$
When testing for absolute convergence I used the n-th term and ratio test, and got inconclusive for both using: $$ |a_n| = {1 \over 2n+1} $$

I'm not sure what test to use to test for absolute convergence, but I then tested for condition convergence making sure that:

1. $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$
2. $a_{n} > a_{n+1}$ (which I found to be true by taking the derivative of $a_n$)
3. $a_n > 0$

I found all these to be true, so I think it is conditionally convergent.

Comment: That's correct.  It is not absolutely convergent but is conditionally convergent.

Comment: @KCd But how do I show that it is not absolute convergent? My teacher won't accept just inconclusives because it looks like another test could work if those don't

Comment: Take the absolute value of the terms and just look at the series you get. Think about a comparison with a more easily determined divergent positive series.

Comment: @KCd I could compare it to just 1/2n, which is larger I think, but doesn't 1/2n converge to 0?

Comment: @Jay Yes, $\;\dfrac1{2n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ , yet **the series** $\;\sum\dfrac1{2n}\;$ diverges as it is a (constant) multiple of the harmonic series.

Comment: You need to compare to a series whose terms are *smaller* and diverges if you want to show your series diverges by comparison; a series of larger terms does not help.  Anyway, who cares if the general term goes to 0? The whole *point* of infinite series is that the general term tending to 0 is not a convergence test.

Comment: @Timbuc I see that $\sum {1 \over 2n}$  diverges now, but I thought that if I compare something to $1 \over {2n+1}$  that it has to be smaller and divergent, to prove divergence. And I thought $1 \over 2n$ is larger so it can't prove divergence. Or maybe I'm just wrong about that

Comment: @Jay As you were already said, to use the comparison theorem to show *divergence* you have to  choose a *divergent series* which is smaller (elementwise and for almost all $\;n\;$ ) than yours. In this case, $\;\sum\frac1{2n}\;$ doesn't help since $\;\frac1{2n+1}\le\frac1{2n}\;$

Comment: @Timbuc Ah, I guess I don't see what else there is to compare to then

Comment: @Timbuc Unless I do a limit comparison with $1 \over 2n$ which gives $\infty$, so it wouldn't be absolutely convergent, and then it would only be conditionally

Comment: @Jay Have you even read my answer?! **That's** an example of what "there is" to be compared with...!

Comment: @Timbuc Agh I just can't see it, are you saying you compare it to itself $\sum {1 \over 2n+1}$?

Comment: @Jay, honestly: **have you read my answer at all** ?? I'm comparing there $\;\dfrac1{2n+1}\;$ with $\;\dfrac1{2n+2n}=\dfrac1{4n}\;$ ...what isn't clear here?

Answer (score 1):

The sum is conditionally convergent since, as you showed, it fulfills Leibniz conditions, but it isn't absolutely convergent since

$$\frac1{2n+1}\ge\frac1{2n+2n}=\frac14\cdot\frac1n$$

and the harmonic series diverges.